# Problems in adaption of a blueprint column chart with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, tikz-pic

I use the following working code as a blueprint for my wishes.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=20pt,
        %
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=above,
        point meta=rawy,
        %
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        %
        ylabel=$\mathrm{kWh/m^2a}$,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250,300},
        enlargelimits=auto,
        %
        xlabel= Sanierter Geb\"audeteil,
        symbolic x coords ={Unrenoviert,Fenster,H\"ulle,Bodenplatte,Heizung},
        x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east},
        ]
    
        \addplot[fill=green] coordinates {
          (Unrenoviert,220.6)
          (Fenster,219.26)
          (H\"ulle,197.67)
          (Bodenplatte,167.9)
          (Heizung,40)
        };
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I changed the line `symbolic x coords ={Unrenoviert,Fenster,H\"ulle,Bodenplatte,Heizung}` into    `symbolic x coords ={Unter 18, 18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55 bis 64, 65 und älter}`, because i neet other symbolix features and get an error.

Also some other things are wrong. I would like to convert a Excel Grafik into LaTex. For me seems to be harder then expected. It would be nice, if you can give me some hints. Thank you!

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=20pt,
        %
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=above,
        point meta=rawy,
        %
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        %
        ylabel=Anzahl,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4},
        enlargelimits=auto,
        %
        xlabel= Alter,
        symbolic x coords ={{Unter 18}, {18-24}, {25-34}, {35-44}, {45-54}, {55 bis 64}, {65 und \"alter}},
        x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east},
        ]
        \addplot[fill=green] coordinates {
          ({Unter 18}, 0)
          ({18-24}, 1)
          ({25-34}, 4)
          ({35-44}, 0)
          ({45-54}, 2)
          ({55-64}, 0)
          ({65 und \"alter}, 0)
        };
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I got this error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `55-64' has not been defi
ned with 'symbolic x coords={{Unter 18}, {18-24}, {25-34}, {35-44}, {45-54}, {5
5 bis 64}, {65 und \"alter}}... Maybe it has been misspelled? Or did you mean s
omething like [normalized]55-64?.
```

[image]

Comment: Wrapping your text in `{...}` such as `Unter 18` will solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the text which contains special characters such as blank space, `[` or `]` ect. with parentheses `{...}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=20pt,
        %
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=above,
        point meta=rawy,
        %
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        %
        ylabel=$\mathrm{kWh/m^2a}$,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250,300},
        enlargelimits=auto,
        %
        xlabel= Sanierter Geb\"audeteil,
        symbolic x coords ={{Unter 18}, {18-24}, {25-34}, {35-44}, {45-54}, {55 bis 64}, {65 und älter}},
        x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east},
        ]
        \addplot[fill=green] coordinates {
          (Unrenoviert,220.6)
          (Fenster,219.26)
          (H\"ulle,197.67)
          (Bodenplatte,167.9)
          (Heizung,40)
        };
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

I think you can divide `symbolic x coords` into `xtick`, `xticklabels` and use real coordinats.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=20pt,
        %
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=above,
        point meta=rawy,
        %
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        %
        ylabel=Anzahl,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4},
        enlargelimits=auto,
        %
        xlabel= Alter,
%         symbolic x coords ={{Unter 18},{18-24},{25-34},{35-44},{45-54},{55 bis 64},{65 und \"alter}},
        xtick={1,2,...,7},
        xticklabels={{Unter 18},{18-24},{25-34},{35-44},{45-54},{55 bis 64},{65 und \"alter}},
        x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east},
        ]
        \addplot[fill=green] coordinates {
          (1, 0)
          (2, 1)
          (3, 4)
          (4, 0)
          (5, 2)
          (6, 0)
          (7, 0)
        };
      \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT 2

Remove these lines to remove the text over the bar.

```
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align=above,
point meta=rawy,
```

Add `title=Title` to add a title.

Check if you have such code `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`, if not add to your codes, then `Alter` will be in right place.

At last, I suggest you to learn to search key words in the documentation, and you will get quicker help.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ZhiyuanLck! I edited the code below with your changes. I also edit the x, y axis and add the correct data to it. It doesn't work. I receive the error i posted in the edited answer... Thanks for hints!

Comment: I have edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Errors are gone!

Some problems are still remaining: I want to remove the numbers over the seven datasample. In my case 0 for "Unter 18" and so on! I marked in the picture!
Second thing is, that i want to move the "Alter" a little bit as marked in the picture.
Third thing is, I like to give a title to the diagramm. Also marked in the picture.
If you can give me some hints, I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! With some further research - as you mentioned - I get to my points. Thank you!